# Recording Video and Audio ARCore iOS SDK

Tags: android, ios, avfoundation, scenekit, arcore

Am using ARCore iOS SDK for Argumented Faces, and am wondering is there a way to record video and audio with ARCore, i want user to tap on record button and after recording the video is saved on there phone. Any help. Thanks